# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected <element> in complexType

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl

When trying to connect to a web service using the following

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://vocab.ndg.nerc.ac.uk/1.1/VocabServerAPI_dl.wsdl");
```

I get this error message

Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing Schema: unexpected  in complexTyp

Which seems odd as all I am doing is trying to connect to it not use any functions from it.

Does anyone know what would be causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSDL itself.  There is something wrong with the way the WSDL is written when this error comes up.  What exactly?  I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like I'll need to contact the web service provider.